# What will happen if we have an empty child class in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Will the child class have access to the parent class's methods?

```
class Parent{
  private String s;

  public Parent(){
     s = "hi";
  }

  public String getS(){
    return s;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. The child can access all public, protected and package access methods and fields. This is not changed by the fact that the child is "empty". It does not even need an explicit constructor since the parent only has a parameterless one.

Comment: So it doesn't need to have a constructor?

Comment: It will inherit the default constructor.

Comment: It only needs to have a constructor if the parent does not have default constructor or it is not accessable.

Comment: Would the compiler even include it if it's never referenced?

Comment: @triplem "Inherit" is probably the wrong word. A default constructor will be _generated_ by the compiler, with the same visibility as the class, if no other constructor is explicitly defined. The default constructor will invoke the no-arg constructor of the parent class. Note if there is no such constructor in the parent class then the compiler will force you to define a constructor in the child class and explicitly call `super(/* the args */)`.

Comment: @RichardBarker Yes, because every class needs a constructor. Even if you don't reference the constructor doesn't mean someone else using your code won't reference it. And don't forget reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Its not mandatory to define a constructor in a child class because there will be a default constructor, but if you intend to change any properties of the Parent Class when instantiating Child Class, you may define a constructor and inside you can access and change the properties of parent class.

```
class Child extends Parent{
  public Child() {
  s = "hi hi hi"
  }
}
```